# Really confused on iTunes connect guide in respect to App file size

Tags: ios, binary, app-store-connect

I am prepearing my first game for submission and reading the iTunes connect [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf) I don't understand the guide's section below.

**From section currently titled "App file size limit" at page 237:**

> (iOS only) App Size iOS apps can be as large as 2 GB, but the
>   executable file cannot exceed 60MB. However, consider download times
>   when determining your app’s size. Minimize the file’s size as much as
>   possible, keeping in mind that there is a 50 MB limit for over-the-air
>   downloads. Abnormally large binary files are usually the result of
>   storing data, such as images, inside the compiled binary itself,
>   instead of as a resource inside your app bundle. If you are compiling
>   an image or large dataset into your binary, it would be best to split
>   this data out into a resource that is loaded dynamically by your app.

**My Doubt:** I estimated the size of the archive using XCode -> Archive and then XCode->Organizer->Estimate App Size and my App is 156 MB of size. This is way more than the 60 MB of limit. How can I make sure the assets are loaded dynamically?

I placed all my images (more than 30 files for a total of 100 MB and all my music (about 30 MB of music) in the Resources folder. I asked the same question on the Apple developer forum but someone just gave me an [answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/917509#917509) than lead me to think that the Apple guide actually refers to the estimated size (not sure if I interpreted the answer wrongly).

Looking at the AppStore there are examples of apps that have a file size higher than 50 MB ([example](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/street-fighter-iv/id354655665)) so I don't understand why the user just told me that I have to look at both executable and non execuatable parts of my app:

> "The "executable file" in question is the entire application bundle
>   file, executable and non-executable parts combined."

Would anyone be able to clarify this?

Comment: The 60MB limit is just for the app binary. This does not include any other files in the resource bundle.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find the App binary information? I checked the "Real time memory usage" but this refers to the amount of dynamic RAM and SWAP memory used by the App I guess and not the file size.

Comment: Build your app. Find the .app folder. Find the binary - it will have the same name as your app. Look at how big it is in Finder or a terminal.

Comment: Ok, excellent, thanks a lot. It says that the executable Unix binary file inside the .App folder is only 6.9 MB, so should be fine. Big help. Wish it was clearer in the documentation :). Please move the comment as answer and will accept it straight away.